# PHP Get numerical entities for a string / email obfuscation

Tags: javascript, php, email, unicode, ascii

I have a e-mail adress in plaintext and want to find it on a given website. Sometimes the websites use "html encoded e-mail adresses" like this (just a few characters for example)

```
&#x69;&#x68;&#x72;&#x65;
```

How can I get this with PHP? (I know this form of "encoding" not give any security at all.)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: It's not ineffective if it's stumping you as it is, no? ;)

Comment: html_entitiy_decode will decode these characters, but I want to encode it. htmlentities() will not encode all characters. I think ord("a") gives me the right information but is there another func?

Comment: If you are using a proper HTML parser, you should get HTML entities decoded automatically. I guess you're into regexp-based HTML parsing :-?

Comment: That's a good point and maybe less complicated. I just questioned my self if there is any way to do this and I ended up with my piece of code, because I didn't found a out-of-the-box function. (I usually Use phpQuery for this)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I will not win a code-beauty-contest with this, but it helped me out and works

```
    $email = str_split($email);

    foreach ($email as $pos) {
        print '&#'. str_pad( ord($pos), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ';';
    }
```

Comment: I really would appreciate if you post a better solution, instead of a down-vote. :-)